# How to check if a group in Xamarin.Forms CollectionView exists

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I'm looking for a way to procedurally add an item to an itemgroup in Xamarin.Forms.

For example (like the official tutorial):
There is a type 'animal' and a type 'animalgroup', which can contain multiple 'animal'.

I can create an 'animalgroup' as well as adding an 'animal' to this group. I then can display these groups within a CollectionView.

Now I'd like to add a new 'animal' to an existing 'animalgroup'.

What is a good approach to 'select' the correct 'animalgroup' with a specific name (e.g. Monkeys)?

Comment: Could you provide a minimal code for clarification ?

Comment: you would check the datasource, not the CollectionView itself